Differential Amplifier Output Ringing
I designed this circuit. It is a fully differential amplifier of gain one. I am getting this ringing and noise on the output of tx1_o
Blue is where the probe is and ground is on circuit's ground.
Here is with the probe on 1x

I have put a 100nF cap in series with the measurement point to AC couple the signal into the RFSoC ADC. This is on the leg of the cap that is AC coupled and on the ADC side. (10x probe)

This is measuring on the leg of the cap that has the source signal, the opposite leg of the one depicted above. Still too noisy but spikes are gone on this side. Note: this is the same place of measurement depicted in the 1x probe picture (below is 10x probe).

Here is where I am taking a measurement (this is on the signal generator side):

Path that the signal is taking:

Here is the signal measured at the source tx_loopback or tx0 WITHOUT the ADC connected:

Here is the signal measured at the source tx_loopback or tx0 WITH the ADC connected (it is more attenuated and noisy):

What can I do to remove this ringing and what could be causing it?


Could you use a 10x probe, show us the input signal, and show us where the probe tip and probe ground are, please? What are the differences between a x1 and a x10 osciloscope probe

@AndrewMorton Thanks for your reply. I have edited the above post and included more information to help.

@Ishmael do you have any capacitance on your power rails? Also, a clearer schematic would be helpful (its impossible to read most of the text)

@BeB00 Hey thanks for responding. I have included a better picture of the schematic as well as some more pictures for clarity.

you have long wires all over the place - does anything change when you move the wires around?

I moved all the wires around while watching the signal. They are all coax shielded cables.  No effect on signal from moving them.

Could you try and disconnect C2?

@Tyassin I disconnected C2 but no luck... No change in the signal.

For the last two scope images: is the "fuzziness" due to noise or unstable behaviour?  You can get a better idea by zooming in (faster time base).  If the waveform is repeating (the image is relatively stable when triggering is continuous) then it is likely to be unstable behaviour.  If the image is still fuzzy, ie: the image is not repeating then likely to be noise.   Suggest also get single-shots ie: trigger just once.

Question 2: please show the following scope images using x10 probes in all cases:  two channels captured simultaneously:  A: CH1= TX0_i, CH2=TX1_i.  B: CH1= TX0_o,  CH2=TX1_o.   Question 3: how many channels on your scope?  Please include a photo of your entire work bench, showing the test equipment available to you.

It's rare that simulation can help in such cases, but it might now. The original schematic shows a high frequency oscillation when the supply voltage is applied.

The amplitude of this can be reduced by lowering the value of the resistors and capacitors, but it is not completely eliminated. If the input signal is a square wave, it occurs only at the edges, for a sine wave, it is more pronounced the smaller the input signal. The impedance of the VOCM input is quite high (Ib=11 µA), capacitive filtering improved it a bit, but did not solve the original problem. The only option was to produce a half supply voltage with a lower impedance. This clearly fixed the circuit in the simulation with the original components without any other modifications. Based on this suggestion plus two 1 kΩ resistors and we will see if the simulation was useful (R9 and R10).

